# pointing to the first array element with the help of a double pointer not working

Tags: c

What's wrong here with pointing a pointer to another pointer?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[2]={7,8};

    int **k;

    k=&a;

    printf("%d",**k);

    return 0;
}
```

The array name in a pointer to the base address I guess so what's wrong here when I am trying to point to it with a double pointer?

Comment: `a` is an *array* of `int`, not a pointer. Pointers and arrays are often interchangeable, but they are not equivalent.

Comment: the array name is a pointer to the base address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have single pointer to point your the first location of your array and print it. I don't see a need for a double pointer.

The assignment

```
int *k = a;
```

The pointer k is made to point to the first location of the array which is given by `a`.
A double pointer is used to point to a pointer and here `a` is not a pointer.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[2]={7,8};

    int *k;

    k=&a;

    printf("%d\n",*k);
    printf("%d\n",*(k+1));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you but if a were not a pointer how does the assignment int *k=a work ?

Comment: @New_Bee Basically pointer variable should hold some valid memory location.Here `a` is a valid memory location. So you can just use that value and give it to the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Under C99 or above you can make use of [compound literals](http://www.9wy.net/onlinebook/CPrimerPlus5/ch10lev1sec9.html):

```
int **k;

k = &((int *){a});
```

But as pointed out by Gopi, in this case a single pointer is enough.